# SpriteKit: How to prevent two SKSpriteNodes from colliding (in Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicscontact

I am making a relatively simple game consisting of a player, obstacles, and coins. My goal is to have collisions between the obstacles and the player only, and for contact between the player and a coin to trigger `didBeginContact`.

Here's some code:

```
//declare categoryBitMasks
struct physicsCategories {
    static let playerCategory : UInt32 = 1
    static let coinCategory: UInt32 = 2
    static let obstacleCategory : UInt32 = 3 
}

//assign physics categories 
playerNode!.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCategories.playerCategory
playerNode!.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCategories.obstacleCategory
playerNode!.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategories.coinCategory


obstacleNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCategories.obstacleCategory
obstacleNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCategories.playerCategory
obstacleNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0


coinNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCategories.coinCategory
coinNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
coinNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategories.playerCategory
```

The `didBeginContact` function removes the coin from the view and adds one to the users currency bank. This function calls when the player hits the coin, but a collision occurs before the coin is removed. The collision is very disruptive of the gameplay and I have been unable to find a working solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: your problem is your categories,  search how bit masks work. You can't do 1,2,3  they have to be powers of 2

Comment: @Knight0fDragon so what could I do instead, 2, 4, 8?

Comment: yes 1,2,4,8,16   or an easy way to understand 0x1 << 0, 0x1 << 1, 0x1 << 2 etc

Comment: @Knight0fDragon that did it, thank you! If you would like to post that as an answer I will mark it correct.

Comment: I am actually looking for a similar question and marking this duplicate,  since it has been asked before.

Comment: I dunno I am having a hard time finding it,  I have answered this before, but I guess the other guy deleted it.  If somebody sees it, please mark this a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your categories, search how bit masks work. You can't do 1,2,3 they have to be powers of 2; 0x1 << 0, 0x1 << 1, 0x1 << 2 etc